# Get events from facebook - token expiration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the latest event from a fanpage/user and show it on a blog. Everything work well with the Graph API but the problem is, that I need a access_token (currently I use a access_token, generated from account).

But the problem is that the token expires (also the offline token).. what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Renew it sometimes as user logs in your application. The normal expiration time is 2 months now (iirc)

Comment: I have not a real application or authorization on this website

Comment: you asked the best way - I answered. If you don't think it's suitable for you - update the original question with **ALL** important details so that we don't guess

Comment: sorry, but I thought it is clear when I write "show it on a blog", that there is no sign in/up or login and I can't regenerate the token

Comment: it wasn't and it is not clear at all. If you don't have persistent storage and you don't have an active user session - I cannot imagine how you get it worked.

Comment: Page access tokens and app access tokens don’t expire by default – but if they’ll allow you to access the data you want depends on things like the event’s privacy settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a fanpage event, you should be able to use the page access token of the given page to retrieve the data. This will be possible following scenario 5 in https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/. As to a user's event, you can extend the token for two months at most also described here https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/.

To get it working on your blog would not be easy as you would need a way to reauth the user every two months when the tokens expire.

Facebook has moved away from the concept of offline tokens because they present a huge security risk for users as they may forget about the application. If a user has not used your application in two months, it is reasonable for Facebook to remove user authorization of your app.